# Django settings: raise KeyError, raise ImproperlyConfigured or use defaults?

Tags: python, django, django-settings

Django expects you to use environment variables in `settings.py` to adapt to multiple environments (e.g. local, heroku, AWS).

I guess I should define -for instance- the username of the DB in an environment variable `DB_USERNAME`. How should I read it?

```
import os
DB_USERNAME = os.environ['DB_USERNAME']
DB_USERNAME = os.environ.get('DB_USERNAME')
DB_USERNAME = os.environ.get('DB_USERNAME', 'john')
```

Should I capture the KeyError and raise a [ImproperlyConfigured](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured) myself?
I prefer to make the app stop rather than run it using incorrect settings (defaults, people forgetting to set a variable,etc).

In the case of the defaults, it might even happen that john exists both loaclly and remotely, but with different permissions. It doesn't look very robust.

Comment: Don't you think its a bad idea to have your DB name in your OS env variable ?

Comment: its db username not db name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach to what you are doing.

I use the following process:

1. Create a `.env` or `.ini` file with your environment variables in it:

   ```
   DB_USERNAME=myDB
   A_NUMBER=1
   ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost, 127.0.0.1, my_host
   DEBUG=False
   MY_DJANGO_KEY=no_peeking_this_is_secret
   ```
2. Use [`decouple.config`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-decouple) -which will make your life easier- to read you `.env`/`.ini` file:

   on `settings.py`:

   ```
   from decouple import Csv, config

   DEBUG = config('DEBUG', cast=bool, default=True)
   A_NUMBER = config('A_NUMBER') # No cast needed!
   ALLOWED_HOSTS = config('ALLOWED_HOSTS', cast=Csv(), default='')
   ...
   ```

That will allow you to have multiple `.env` or `.ini` files for each of your possible configurations and you won't have to worry about mixing up permissions etc.

Finally, I tend to **use defaults** with the lowest allowances possible (ex. look at my default allowed hosts which is an empty string).
But if there exists some very important variable that must be set correctly, then:

- The `config()` method will raise a `UndefinedValueError` if a variable is undefined and no defaults are set.
- We can therefore create a `try:... except:` block to anticipate that:

  ```
  try:
      SUPER_IMPORTANT_VAR = config('SUPER_IMPORTANT_VAR')
  except UndefinedValueError:
      print('Hey!! You forgot to set SUPER_IMPORTANT_VAR!!')
  ```

Comment: thanks! rather than mixing up permissions (related to the example of my user john), I was concerned about having defaults hiding real errors. if you use default='' in allowed hosts, the site will not work and you'll notice, but should that be more explicit by raising an ImproperlyConfigured err? I'm thinking about a redis URL, a cache prefix, pagination size, or something that might not be used until later.

Comment: If you have something that you want to absolutely be a set variable, then you can do: `SUPER_IMPORTANT_VAR = config('SUPER_IMPORTANT_VAR')` which, if the variable is undefined, will raise a `UndefinedValueError`! I will edit my answer :)

Comment: ah I see! yeah, I wanted to focus on making it robust, fail early and prevent unexpected behaviour or accidental mistakes rather than the origin of this value.

Comment: Not a bad approach what you are saying @EduardGamonal !